# Pytsk - Sending files to a server from a disk image

Tags: python, server, paramiko

I am trying to send each file from a disk image to a remote server using paramiko.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect('xxx', username='xxx', password='xxx')

    def send_file(self, i_node, name):
        sftp = self.ssh.open_sftp()
        serverpath = '/home/paul/Testing/'
        try:
            sftp.chdir(serverpath)
        except IOError:
            sftp.mkdir(serverpath)
            sftp.chdir(serverpath)
        serverpath = '/home/Testing/' + name

        sftp.putfo(fs.open_meta(inode = i_node), serverpath)
```

However when I run this I get an error saying that "pytsk.File has no attribute read".

Is there any other way of sending this file to the server?

Comment: Please edit your code snippet to include your dependencies/imports. You are likely to get more help that way, as this relies on a specific Python module most forum users might not be familiar with. Your "fs" variable just appears from somewhere and we do not know how you initialise it and what file system might be behind.

Comment: There might be nothing wrong with Paramiko part and the mechanism used to send over a file. It might just be a problem using pytsk, and to understand that it is crucial to know what "fs" is in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick investigation I think I found what your problem is.  Paramiko's sftp.putfo expects a Python file object as the first parameter. The file object of Pytsk3 is a completely different thing. Your sftp object tries to perform "read" on this, but Pytsk3 file object does not have a method "read", hence the error.

You *could* in theory try expanding Pytsk3.File class and adding this method but I would not hold my breath that it actually works.

I would just read the file to a temporary one and send that. Something like this (you would need to make temp file name handling more clever and delete the file afterwards but you will get the idea):

```
serverpath = '/home/Testing/' + name
tmp_path = "/tmp/xyzzy"
file_obj = fs.open_meta(inode = i_node)

# Add here tests to confirm this is actually a file, not a directory 

tha = open(tmp_path, "wb")
tha.write(file_obj.read_random(0, file_obj.info.meta.size))
tha.close()

rha = open(tmp_path, "rb")
sftp.putfo(rha, serverpath)
rha.close()
# Delete temp file here
```

Hope this helps. This will read the whole file in memory from fs image to be written to temp file, so if the file is massive you would run out of memory.

To work around that, you should read the file in chunks looping through it with read_random in suitable chunks (the parameters are start offset and amount of data to read), allowing you to construct the temp file in a chunks of for example a couple of megabytes.

This is just a simple example to illustrate your problem.

Hannu

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like this but I am using the program to perform a full disk acquisition and I was worried that this would write to the disk

Comment: You can try  extending Pytsk3.File and add a read() method that would then use self.read_random to read the actual data. It might even work but I didn't try it.   But if you choose the temporary path to reside on the local filesystem you use to boot your acquisition device, I see no reason why it would write on the target drive.